# Remove row from the CSV file if condition met

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape pickels.com.au.

I am trying to update the pickels_dataset.csv file if the link is the same and if the price is not the same them I am removing the list and inserting the new row to the CSV file, but it doesn't remove the old entry from the CSV file.

What would be the best way to remove and update the row in the CSV file.

Below is my code...

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import csv
import re
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep


with open('pickels_dataset.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as auction_csv_file:
    auction_csv_writer = csv.writer(auction_csv_file)
    live_auctions_api = 'https://www.pickles.com.au/PWR-Web/services/api/sales/future'
    api_request = requests.get(url=live_auctions_api)
    for auctions in api_request.json():
        auction_link = auctions.get('viewSaleListingLink')
        if 'cars/item/search/-/listing/listSaleItems/' in auction_link:
            auction_request = requests.get(url=auction_link)
            response = Selector(text=auction_request.text)

            sales_id_re = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "Product_Type_Sequence")]/text() | //script[contains(text(), "lot_number_suffix_sequence")]/text()').get()
            sales_id = re.findall(r'"Product_Type_Sequence";var n="(.*?)"', sales_id_re) or re.findall(r'"lot_number_suffix_sequence";var n="(.*?)"', sales_id_re)
            if sales_id == []:
                continue
            auction_sale_link = f'https://www.pickles.com.au/v4/caradvert/saleid-{sales_id[0]}-public?count=true&inav=Car%7Cbc%7Cha%7Cu&q=(And.ProductType.Vehicles._.Year.range(2010..2021).)&sr=%7Clot_number_suffix_sequence%7C0%7C30'
            auction_sale_link_requests = requests.get(url=auction_sale_link)

            auctions_data = auction_sale_link_requests.json().get('SearchResults')
            if auctions_data == []:
                print("NO RESULTS")
            for auction_data in auctions_data:
                if int(auction_data.get('MinimumBid')) > 0:
                    ids = auction_data.get('TargetId')
                    main_title = auction_data.get('Title')
                    short_title = str(auction_data.get('Year')) + ' ' + str(auction_data.get('Make')) + ' ' + str(auction_data.get('Model'))
                    make = auction_data.get('M ake')
                    model = auction_data.get('Model')
                    variant = auction_data.get('Series')
                    transmission = auction_data.get('Transmission')
                    odometer = auction_data.get('Odometer')
                    state = auction_data.get('Location').get('State')
                    sale_price = auction_data.get('MinimumBid')
                    link_path = main_title.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '-').replace(',', '-') + '/' + str(ids)
                    link = f'https://www.pickles.com.au/cars/item/-/details/{link_path}'
                    sale_date = auction_data.get('SaleEndString')
                    
                    auction_values = [
                        main_title, short_title, make, 
                        model, variant, transmission, odometer, 
                        state, "${:,.2f}".format(sale_price).strip() , 
                        link, sale_date
                    ]
                    
                    with open('pickels_dataset.csv', 'r+') as csv_read:
                        auction_reader = list(csv.reader(csv_read))
                        for each in auction_reader:
                            if link in each:
                                each_link, each_price = each[9], each[0]
                                if (link == each_link) and (sale_price != each_price):
                                    auction_reader.clear()
                                    print('New list found, old list deleted')
                                    auction_csv_writer.writerow(auction_values)
                                    print('New value added')
                                    continue
                                elif (link == each[9]) and (sale_price == each[0]):
                                    print('Same result already exist in the file')
                                    continue
                        else:
                            auction_csv_writer.writerow(auction_values)
                            print('Unique result found and added.')
                            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current script is opening your auction CSV file for appending, and then whilst it is still open, attempting to open it again for reading. This is probably why it is not updating as expected.

A better approach would be to first read the entire contents of your existing saved auction file into a dictionary. The key could be the `link` which would then make it easy to determine if you have already seen an existing auction.

Next scrape the current auctions and update the `saved_auctions` dictionary as needed.

Finally at the end, write the contents of `saved_auctions` back to the CSV file.

For example:

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import csv
import re


auction_filename = 'pickels_dataset.csv'

# Load existing auctions into a dictionary with link as key
saved_auctions = {}

with open(auction_filename, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_auction_file:
    for row in csv.reader(f_auction_file):
        saved_auctions[row[9]] = row      # dictionary key is link
    
live_auctions_api = 'https://www.pickles.com.au/PWR-Web/services/api/sales/future'
api_request = requests.get(url=live_auctions_api)

for auctions in api_request.json():
    auction_link = auctions.get('viewSaleListingLink')
    
    if 'cars/item/search/-/listing/listSaleItems/' in auction_link:
        auction_request = requests.get(url=auction_link)
        response = Selector(text=auction_request.text)

        sales_id_re = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "Product_Type_Sequence")]/text() | //script[contains(text(), "lot_number_suffix_sequence")]/text()').get()
        sales_id = re.findall(r'"Product_Type_Sequence";var n="(.*?)"', sales_id_re) or re.findall(r'"lot_number_suffix_sequence";var n="(.*?)"', sales_id_re)
        
        if sales_id == []:
            continue
        
        auction_sale_link = f'https://www.pickles.com.au/v4/caradvert/saleid-{sales_id[0]}-public?count=true&inav=Car%7Cbc%7Cha%7Cu&q=(And.ProductType.Vehicles._.Year.range(2010..2021).)&sr=%7Clot_number_suffix_sequence%7C0%7C30'
        auction_sale_link_requests = requests.get(url=auction_sale_link)

        auctions_data = auction_sale_link_requests.json().get('SearchResults')
        
        if auctions_data == []:
            print("NO RESULTS")
        
        for auction_data in auctions_data:
            if int(auction_data.get('MinimumBid')) > 0:
                ids = auction_data.get('TargetId')
                main_title = auction_data.get('Title')
                short_title = str(auction_data.get('Year')) + ' ' + str(auction_data.get('Make')) + ' ' + str(auction_data.get('Model'))
                make = auction_data.get('Make')
                model = auction_data.get('Model')
                variant = auction_data.get('Series')
                transmission = auction_data.get('Transmission')
                odometer = auction_data.get('Odometer')
                state = auction_data.get('Location').get('State')
                minimum_bid = auction_data.get('MinimumBid')
                sale_price = "${:,.2f}".format(minimum_bid).strip()
                link_path = main_title.replace(' ', '-').replace('/', '-').replace(',', '-') + '/' + str(ids)
                link = f'https://www.pickles.com.au/cars/item/-/details/{link_path}'
                sale_date = auction_data.get('SaleEndString')
                
                auction_values = [
                    main_title, short_title, make, 
                    model, variant, transmission, odometer, 
                    state, sale_price, 
                    link, sale_date
                ]

                if link in saved_auctions:
                    if saved_auctions[link][8] == sale_price:
                        print('Same result already exists in the file')
                    else:
                        print('New value updated')
                        saved_auctions[link] = auction_values        # Updated the entry
                else:
                    print('New auction added')
                    saved_auctions[link] = auction_values
                    
# Update the saved auction file                    
with open(auction_filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f_auction_file:
    csv_auction_file = csv.writer(f_auction_file)
    csv_auction_file.writerows(saved_auctions.values())
```

If you want to also remove auctions that are no longer active, then it would probably be best to simply ignore the saved file and just write all current entries as is.